# Upstart job in systemd format

Tags: 16.04, upstart, systemd

I have looked at [the official docs for start-up](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#Example_Systemd_service), but I failed to replicate my Upstart job to systemd.

Upstart Job:

```
description  "evercam_media"
start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
limit nofile 1000000 1000000

respawn
chdir /
setuid root
setgid root

exec watch -n1 '/usr/local/bin/run_evercam_media.sh'

post-stop exec sudo pkill beam
```

I have replicated almost the same while reading the doc files as

```
[Unit]
Description=evercam_media
[Service]
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/
ExecStart=/bin/sh -ec "exec watch -n1 '/usr/local/bin/run_evercam_media.sh'"
ExecStopPost=sudo pkill beam
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when ever I do `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl status evercam_media.service` I only get the errors as

```
● evercam_media.service - evercam_media
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/evercam_media.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-07-18 08:41:23 CEST; 12s ago
  Process: 32596 ExecStart=/bin/sh -ec exec watch -n1 '/usr/local/bin/run_evercam_media.sh' (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 32596 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 18 08:41:22 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal systemd[1]: evercam_media.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 18 08:41:22 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal systemd[1]: evercam_media.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 18 08:41:23 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal systemd[1]: evercam_media.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 18 08:41:23 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal systemd[1]: Stopped evercam_media.
Jul 18 08:41:23 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal systemd[1]: evercam_media.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 18 08:41:23 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal systemd[1]: Failed to start evercam_media.
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal:/etc/systemd/system#
```

As they have mentioned in the docs.. 
`exec` is going to be `/bin/sh 'exec'` So I have tried it as above but it fails. But If I just do this in terminal `exec watch -n1 '/usr/local/bin/run_evercam_media.sh'` Everything gets started.

UPDATE:

I just want to run the sh script everyone 1 second and `Watch` is the tool I have ended with to use.

Comment: How about a more minimal service file? http://paste.ubuntu.com/25117471/

Comment: `Jul 18 08:31:54 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal systemd[1]: Started evercam_media.
Jul 18 08:31:54 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal sh[32175]: Error opening terminal: unknown.
Jul 18 08:31:54 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal systemd[1]: evercam_media.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE`

Comment: So you see the problem: `watch` assumes it's run with a controlling TTY. Why do you need `watch`
 anyway?

Comment: I have no idea, I am just assigned a task to create the upstart to systemd, I struggled and thats what I got, we can remove watch. but I just need it to start running.

Comment: Then go back and ask. That you're assigned a task doesn't mean you to be a grunt and do it without thinking. Clarify why `watch` is needed.